# Ability to use the property of the 2 functions for the same data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

mycode is below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
m=np.random.randint(1,20,size=(5,3 ))
df1=pd.DataFrame(m,columns=["a","b","c"])

##### function 1: color customization in data frame
def color_negative_red1(val):
    
    if val > 9:
     color = 'red'
    else :
     color =  'green' 
    return 'color: %s' % color



df1.style.applymap(color_negative_red1)  #FİRST: show this in data frame

########### function 2: highlighted max values

def highlight_max(data, color='yellow'):   
    '''
    highlight the maximum in a Series or DataFrame
    '''
    attr = 'background-color: {}'.format(color)
    if data.ndim == 1:  # Series from .apply(axis=0) or axis=1
        is_max = data == data.max()
        return [attr if v else '' for v in is_max]
    else:  # from .apply(axis=None)
        is_max = data == data.max().max()
        return pd.DataFrame(np.where(is_max, attr, ''),
                            index=data.index, columns=data.columns)
df1.style.apply(highlight_max, color='darkorange', axis=None) #SECOND: show this in same data frame too.
```

Hello friends, I want to use both "color_negative_red1(val)" and highlighted max values functions for same data frame at he same time. But for the moment I could only use one of them for the data frame.
How can I use the property of function 2 for the same data frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
(df1.style.applymap(color_negative_red1)                 # FIRST
    .apply(highlight_max, color='darkorange', axis=None) # SECOND
)
```

Output:

[image]